# 2048: how many sets of moves have I made?

Tags: mathematics, 2048-game

[image: state of 2048 board]

Transcription of board (score 324):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |  |  |
| 32 |  |  | 4 |
| 8 | 16 | 2 | 32 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 2 |

I made moves in the pattern of: right up left down right up left down. How many times have I done this set? (1 set=right up left down)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it could vary because each move does not necessarily combine numbers if I’m not mistaken

Comment: @Bryce that would still would count as a move though, I think this is literally just work out the number of moves same as the last puzzle and then divide by 4 which would make it a dupe, if I'm wrong then fair enough but would need to see an answer showing it is different

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil As the creator of the previous puzzle, I can confirm that this IS a dupe.